# WPF: GridViewColumn resize event

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, resize, gridviewcolumn

I'm using `ListView` with `GridView`. Is there `GridViewColumn` resize event?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at **[MSDN DridViewColumn details](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.gridviewcolumn.aspx).** It does not appaer to have such an event, probably some workaround required, I am not sure though. have [look here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.gridviewcolumn_events.aspx)

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 30):

I will handle the `PropertyChanged` event instead. The `PropertyChanged` event is not seen in the Visual Studio intellisense, but you can trick it :)

```
 GridViewColumn column = ...
 ((System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged)column).PropertyChanged += (sender, e) =>
 {
     if (e.PropertyName == "ActualWidth")
     {
         //do something here...
     }
 };
```

Comment: Very nice (+1). See this for an implentation of this technique in an attached property: http://wpftoolbelt.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/33225#457436.

Answer (score 4):

Although `GridViewColumn` does not appear to have a `Resize` event, you can bind to the `ColumnWidth` property.

You can verify this with sample XAML below - no code behind needed for this example. It binds only in one direction, from the column width to the text box, and when you resize you will see the textbox immediately update with the column width.

(This is just a simple example; if you want to pick up the resize in code I would create a class with a `Width` property so binding will work in both directions).

```
<StackPanel>
    <ListView>
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn Width="{Binding ElementName=tbWidth1, Path=Text, Mode=OneWayToSource}"  />
                <GridViewColumn Width="{Binding ElementName=tbWidth2, Path=Text, Mode=OneWayToSource}"  />
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
        <ListViewItem>Item 1</ListViewItem>
        <ListViewItem>Item 2</ListViewItem>
    </ListView>
    <TextBox Name="tbWidth1" />
    <TextBox Name="tbWidth2" />
</StackPanel>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
private void ListView_Loaded( object sender, RoutedEventArgs e )
{
     // Add the handler to know when resizing a column is done
     ((ListView)sender).AddHandler( Thumb.DragCompletedEvent, new   DragCompletedEventHandler( ListViewHeader_DragCompleted ), true );
}

private void ListViewHeader_DragCompleted( object sender, System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.DragCompletedEventArgs e )
{
     ListView lv = sender as ListView;
    ... code handing the resize goes here ...
}
```

XAML:

```
<ListView Loaded="ListView_Loaded">
```

Comment: Please add some text to help to better explain it

Answer (score 0):

Another approach: you can attach a change event handler to the GridViewColumn `Width` property:

```
PropertyDescriptor pd = DependencyPropertyDescriptor.FromProperty(
    GridViewColumn.WidthProperty, typeof(GridViewColumn));
GridView gv = (GridView)myListView.View;
foreach (GridViewColumn col in gv.Columns) {
    pd.AddValueChanged(col, ColumnWidthChanged);
}

...

private void ColumnWidthChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) { ... }
```

(Inspired by an answer [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/aspnet/en-US/2e1e371a-36b6-40b3-b45b-1908f1569424/datagrid-column-width-changed-event), for a similar question about DataGrid.)